# Queueable Chaining - Not Getting Enqueued?

Tags: queueable-apex

I've got a `Queueable` that I use to perform asynchronous calculations. Because I sometimes have a lot of these operations going on at once (for instance during our data back-fill), I want to make sure that if the operation fails we try again. I am using a [Custom Type in a Set](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_collections_maps_keys_userdefined.htm). The behavior is completely defined by the `Set<CustomKey>`.

```
public class AsyncJob implements Queueable
{
    final Set<CustomKey> keys;
    public AsyncJob(Set<CustomKey> keys) { this.keys = keys; }
    public void execute(QueueableContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            upsert records;
        }
        catch (DmlException dmx)
        {
            system.enqueueJob(new AsyncJob(customKeys));
            throw new CustomException(dmx.getMessage(), dmx);
        }
    }
    public class CustomException extends Exception { }
    public class CustomKey
    {
        public Integer hashCode() { /* return a hash code */ }
        public Boolean equals(Object obj) { /* comparison */ }
    }
}
```

What I would expect from this code is that when something goes wrong with the DML operation, another `Queueable` job should be scheduled. No matter how many jobs fail, I should have one 'Completed' job for each job that I enqueued at the start. So if I try 10 operations and 3 fail, I should have 13 total jobs, 10 successes and 3 failures. But instead what I see is 10 total jobs, 7 sucesses and 3 failures. So it looks like the reschedule is not working. Why would that be?

Comment: what does the customException handler do?  You sure you don't want to fail gracefully, perhaps by logging/sending email to sysad instead?

Comment: I just want to be able to see which jobs failed. Emails would be pretty annoying and they are very careful about adding extra objects. Since there's no log object already logging is a difficult add.

Comment: if CustomException is unhandled, won't that terminate the transaction, rolling back the enqueuedJob ?

Comment: I didn't realize unhandled exceptions would cause a rollback in this context.

Comment: You should be able to verify that with the debug log

Comment: @CaspNZ Queueables do not seem to generate debug logs actually.

Comment: @AdrianLarson They do. Open your Developer Console, and run your queueable again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncaught exceptions cause automatic transactions failures, which ultimately result in the entire transaction rolling back, including any emails that would have been sent, any records that would have been saved, and any jobs that would have been queued (as if the entire transaction had never happened). Do not throw an error if you expect to be able to chain. Instead, consider emailing somebody, writing to a custom log object, etc. Note that in your example, where you had 10 batches, with 7 successes and and 3 failures, would instead appear as 13 successes. You'll probably want to log failures elsewhere so you can tell what happened.